# Securing Client ID key in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, api, security, key

I'm sure someone has asked this before, but I'm struggling to find answers online as most answers relate to OAuth or suggest switching to OAuth.

I am using a third party service that requires I use an API key or Client ID key.  Actually, several.  That's a single key for all users of my app.  I'm developing for iOS and Android both.

Everything works perfectly in my current beta builds, except I'm worried about security.  The key is in my source code.  It's almost certainly, therefore, in the binary, so it could potentially be retrieved.

In fact, one of the API key providers in particular specified that the key should NOT be embedded in a mobile app.

So...how in the world am I supposed to utilize these data services?  Stuff like the Twitch and YouTube API, for example.  You have to submit a client ID (Twitch is mandating this in August), and it seems like you have to embed it in the app.

What is the way to secure it?  Especially if the server doesn't do OAuth?

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to OAuth. Are Client/API keys only used if OAuth isn't implemented? OAuth is for identifying the user, while Client/API keys are for identifying the application. Regardless, it would seem like you could retrieve the API key from the server fairly easily without embedding it in the client, if necessary.